# Openapi v3 dynamic Accept and Content-Type headers

Tags: rest, http, openapi, openapi-generator

For one particular endpoint in OpenAPI v3 spec, I need to manually handle request mime-type. It's a GET request, where the user should specify `Accept` header, and the service loads some data and encodes it into one of multiple supported formats to respond with. I'm trying to specify `Accept` and `Content-Type` in spec:

```
  /example:
    get:
      description: Example endpoint
      operationId: example
      parameters:
        - name: Accept
          in: header
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            '*/*':
              schema:
                type: string
                format: binary
          headers:
            Content-Type:
              description: Content type
              schema:
                format: string
        '404':
          description: Not found
        '406':
          description: Unsupported mime-type
```

But codegen tool print warnings:

```
WARN    Accept is described separately and will be ignored in this section  {"at": "spec.yml:96:11"}
WARN    Content-Type is described separately and will be ignored in this section    {"at": "spec.yml:111:15"}
```

and doesn't generate these headers in code.

How should I pass these dynamic params to request and response?
I don't want to describe all supported mime-types in spec, because the list of supported formats may change dynamically without changing the code, and I don't want need to recompile the server every time I add or remove new mime-type encoder.

Answer (score 0):

To bypass OpenAPI headers restriction, I added middleware to copy original headers into new parameters with `original-` prefix, the Go code is:

```golang
var CopyOriginalHandlersMiddleware = func(req middleware.Request, next middleware.Next) (middleware.Response, error) {
    names := []string{
        "Accept", "Content-Type",
    }
    for _, name := range names {
        header := req.Raw.Header.Get(name)
        var param api.OptString
        if header != "" {
            param = api.NewOptString(header)
        }
        key := strings.ToLower(fmt.Sprintf("original-%s", name))
        req.Params[middleware.ParameterKey{
            Name: key,
            In:   openapi.LocationHeader,
        }] = param
    }
    return next(req)
}
```

In `spec.yaml` I added these headers with `original-` prefix too:

```yaml
      parameters:
        - in: header
          name: original-accept
          required: false
          description: This valus will be populated with Accept header by CopyOriginalHeaders middleware
          schema:
            type: string
```

And now I can access these headers from my generated handler:

```golang
accept, ok := params.OriginalAccept.Get()
```

These examples are for Go language, but I believe that other languages also has middlewares for OpenAPI.